# not able to read value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<results>
  <metadata>
    <column name="title" type="S" length="4000" nullable="true" />
    <column name="schbat" type="S" length="32" nullable="true" />
    <column name="pck_cnt" type="I" length="4" nullable="true" />
  </metadata>
  <data>
    <row>
      <field>Wave</field>
      <field>1209180044-</field>
      <field>4</field>
    </row>
    <row>
      <field>Wave</field>
      <field>1209180045-</field>
      <field>1</field>
    </row>
    <row>
  </data>
</results>
```

- xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:key name="kString" match="field" use="."/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body style="text-align: center;">
           <table width="450" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC" >
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; color: #ba1e29; border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff; border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;"><span style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; text-align: center; font-weight: 500; color: #3f3f3f; line-height: 1; margin-bottom: 1rem; text-transform: uppercase;"><strong>Results For Processing on <span style="color: #ba1e29">5-4-2020</span></strong></span></th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:variable name="set" select="moca-results/metadata/column" />
                <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)" />

                <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$set">
                    <th width="20%" style="font-size:13px;font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;background-color: #f0f0fa; color: #ba1e29; border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff; border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:variable name="bodyset" select="results/data/row" />
                <xsl:variable name="bodycount" select="count($bodyset)" />
                <xsl:variable name="set" select="results/metadata/column" />
                <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$bodyset">
                    <tr>
                       <xsl:for-each select="$set">
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;background-color: #f0f0fa; color: #414143; border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;">
                            <xsl:value-of select="filed" />
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*output

title  |   schbat       |   pck_cnt
Wave   |   1209180044-  |   4
Wave   |   1209180045-  |   1

based on the column count I will get filed in row(means if column count is 3 in metadata then i will get 3 filed in row element. but i am not able to read value those filed(each time when i am , i am always getting wave as result)

Comment: Please add your current XSLT and the expected output to your question.

Comment: Why do you need the column count? Doesn't every row have the same fields? Why not simply create a cell for each?

Comment: sorry by mistake i forgot to remove moca

Comment: @michael.hor257k based on column count it will define how many filed should be their inside row element

Comment: @michael.hor257k i rmoved column count andtried i am always getting wave as output in 3 fileds

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are overcomplicating this. Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<results>
  <metadata>
    <column name="title" type="S" length="4000" nullable="true" />
    <column name="schbat" type="S" length="32" nullable="true" />
    <column name="pck_cnt" type="I" length="4" nullable="true" />
  </metadata>
  <data>
    <row>
      <field>Wave</field>
      <field>1209180044-</field>
      <field>4</field>
    </row>
    <row>
      <field>Wave</field>
      <field>1209180045-</field>
      <field>1</field>
    </row>
  </data>
</results>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/results">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="metadata/column">
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="data/row">
                    <tr>
                       <xsl:for-each select="field">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>title</th>
               <th>schbat</th>
               <th>pck_cnt</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Wave</td>
               <td>1209180044-</td>
               <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Wave</td>
               <td>1209180045-</td>
               <td>1</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your stylesheet is expecting the top-level element to be `moca-results` but it is actually `results`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26170521)

Comment: I beg to differ. The question says that the transformation doesn't work and I have given a reason why it doesn't work.